# Issue with Magento and mercadoenvios

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

No matters what I do, in the checkout proccess where I've written all the shipping address, mercadoenvios shows error saying: sorry, mercadoenvios is not available at the moment..
I have checked twice, and the products have the attributes required by mercadoenvios: width, height, lenght, weight.. And each of them associated to the correspondent var in mercadoenvios..
So, any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I would suggest you use something other than Mercadoenvios, some 3rd party plugins are just coded so badly they don't work out of the box, if you have paid for it, contact support, if you haven't paid for it I know a place where you can ask for recommendations for alternatives.